# what are typescript transform

Tags: angular, typescript

I just read an article on official blog angular 5 (https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced).
There is talk of typescript transform. In detail:

"TypeScript Transforms
Under the hood, the Angular compiler now operates as a TypeScript transform, making incremental rebuilds dramatically faster. TypeScript transforms were a new feature introduced as part of TypeScript 2.3 that allows us to hook into the standard TypeScript compilation pipeline."

I would like to understand better it.
Tranforms or compilation pipeline, what are?
tnx!

Answer (score 4):

This referes to the internals of how the typescript compiler generates Javascript code. Since 2.3 the compiler takes the Typescript AST (abstract syntax tree) and applies a series of transformations (the transformation pipeline). At the end of the pipeline you get a new AST that is a Javascript AST.

From the source code, these are the current transformers:

[image: Typescript Transformers]

So for example when compiling for a `es5` target with `jsx` enabled  and `system` modules the following transforms will be included:

- **transformTypeScript** - Will remove typescript specific annotations
- **transformJsx** - Will remove `jsx` syntax and transform it to Javascript
- **transformESNext** - Will transform `esnext` to `es2017`
- **transformES2017** - Will transform `es2017` to `es2016`
- **transformES2016** - Will transform `es2016` to `es2015`
- **transformES2015** - Will transform `es2015` to `es5` (minus generators)
- **transformGenerators** - Will transform `es2015` generators to `es5`
- **transformSystemModule** - Will add module specific js code.

After all the transformations are applied, writing the AST to a file is a trivial operation.